# Python3: How to force different bound of generic TypeVar on inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, python-typing

Let's suppose following code;

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

class A1:
    x: int = 1

class A2(A1):
    y: int = -1

T = TypeVar("T", bound=A1)

class B1(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, a: T):
        self.a: T = a

class B2(B1):
    def __init__(self, a: T):
        self.a: T = a
```

I want to let user know that parameter(and state) `a` in `B2.__init__` should be a subclass of `A2`, but it seems hard to found such way. The one possible way I found is following;

```py
T2 = TypeVar("T2", bound=A2)

class B2(B1, Generic[T2]):
    def __init__(self, a: T2):
        self.a = a
```

But I don't know what happens to static type checkers if there are two `Generic` classes available. Which way is the most safe and elegant to resolve this situation?

I use Python 3.10.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `B1` class lacks a type parameter in the `B2` declaration. Adding `T2` as a type parameter is correct, as `A2` is a subclass of `A1`.

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


class A1:
    x: int = 1


class A2(A1):
    y: int = -1


T = TypeVar("T", bound=A1)
T2 = TypeVar("T2", bound=A2)


class B1(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, a: T):
        self.a: T = a


class B2(B1[T2]):
    def __init__(self, a: T2):
        self.a = a
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have some question.. When I inherit from `B1[T2]` (i.e. `class B2(B1[T2])`), then `B2` is indexable(I am not sure if this word is correct in this context) like `B2[A2]`, but I thought `B1[T2]` is already specialized type? So in my sight `B2[T2]` looks like `B1[T1][T2]`, I am confused.. Can you explain what happens here in detail?

Comment: `class B2(B1[T2])` means that the class `B2` inherits from `B1` and that the type parameter `T2` has to be compatible with the type parameter declared in the `B1` class declaration - `T1` in that case.

Comment: It is roughly equivalent to `class B2(B1, Generic[T2])` with an additional requirement that `T2` has to be compatible with `T1`.